# Prove that the set of complex arithmetic functions is a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, arithmetic-functions

A complex arithmetic function is a map $f:\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Define $R$ as the set of all such functions. Let the sum of two such functions, denoted as $f_1+f_2$, be defined as

$$(f_1+f_2)(n)=f_1(n)+f_2(n)$$

and the convolution product, denoted as $f_1*f_2$, as

$$(f_1*f_2)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}{f_1(d)f_2(\frac{n}{d})}$$

where the summation is taken over all positive divisors $d$ of $n$.

I have to prove that $R$, together with the summation and product as defined above, forms a (commutative) domain.

I guess that I have to prove all of the ring-axioms one by one (including commutative property) and then prove that $R$ has no zero-divisors. I think the zero would be the function $f_0(n)=0$ for all $n$ and with this, it is pretty straightforward to prove the abelian-group axioms for addition. The additive inverse of some $f(n)$ would be $(-f)(n)=-f(n)$ for all $n$. So far so good. Distributivity is also pretty easy to proof.

But now I have to prove the (other) multiplication axioms, which I simply can't seem to grasp. I'm not even sure what to choose as multiplicative identity, even though the straightforward guess would be to define it as the function $f_1(n)=1$ for all $n$ (please note that in the definition of the operants, the $f_1$ is an arbitrary function, not necessarily the unit). Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

EDIT:

From a comment, I have gathered that $f_1(1)=1, f_1(n)=0$ for $n>1$ works as a $1$, proving the axiom of multiplicative identity.

I still need to prove the following:

Let $f,g,h\in R$, then

$$f*(g*h)=(f*g)*h,$$

$$f*g=g*f$$ and

$$f*g=f_0 \Rightarrow f=f_0\vee g=f_0$$

Comment: What about $f(k)=0$ for $k\ge2$ and $f(1)=1$ as a unit?

Comment: Hey yeah, that works! Thanks, with this it's straightforward to prove the axiom for multiplication with 1.

Comment: I think that now you can point out very clearly where you are stuck: commutativity(?), integral domain(?), and so on.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question accordingly. What do you mean by integral domain, though?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain

Comment: Isn't obvious that $f*g=g*f$? AFAIK the set $\frac nd$ with $d\mid n$ equals the set all divisors of $n$ (backwards, of course).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946512/ring-with-convolution-product

Comment: If $f*g=0$ then $f(1)g(1)=0$, so $f(1)=0$ or $g(1)=0$. Now suppose that $f\ne0$ and $g\ne0$. Consider $f(i)=0$ for $1\le i<r$ and $f(r)\ne0$ and similarly find an $s$ for $g$. Compute $(f*g)(rs)$.